# what is the propper way to use Titanium eventListerner/fireEvent to communication with webview

Tags: webview, titanium

so I'm working on an application that uses webview to display data. At the moment i'm trying to get data from, and send data to the webview. It seems that getting data from the webview works fine, but sending data back to the webview forms the problem.

I use fireEvents and Eventlisteners to communicat. It looks somethhing like this:

webview : index.html

```
// declared at the beginning of the html file
Ti.App.addEventListener('sendToWebview', function(data) {
  alert('alert in webview');
});

// fires when button is pushed
function onClick(){
  Ti.App.fireEvent('sendToTi', { "someDataToTi"  });
}
```

app.js

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('sendToTi', function(data) {        
  alert('alert in Ti');
  Ti.App.fireEvent('sendToWebview', { "someDataToWebview" });
});
```

What works is the sendToTi event. here i always get the alert. What doesn't seem to work all the time is the sendToWebview event. The weird thing is that is sometimes seem to work, other times not and even when I go back to the code that worked, it seems to not work anymore.
What am I doing wrong? is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Is the code `{ "someDataToWebview" }` a placeholder for a real JavaScript object in your code? As written this would cause an exception in either the webview or Titanium, or even both.

Comment: When I try this, I get an error saying "Ti" doesn't exist in my webview. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your '`sendToTi`' is correct. But you can't send events to the WebView in that way.

To execute JavaScript (which is sending events) in your WebView you can use

```javascript
webview.evalJS('someJSFunction(with, parameters, for, instance);');
webview.evalJS('alert("Hello World!");');
```

There is no need of EventListeners (especially no app-wide event listeners).

Comment: thanks, for the reply,
I figured out what the problem is. It seems to be that the webview caches previous pages by itself. This makes that the javascript inside the HTML is not being executed. The eventlisteners and fireEvents are working from- and to- the webview. The thing is that it only works the first time the app is launched or when the app is fully closed and opened again. 

The problem now is, how to clean/disable the cache for the webview? any thoughts on that?

Comment: [Try this](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/139315/clear-webview-cache--cookies) or set the cache-policy of your page... And mark this answer as correct, open a new question for your cache problem.